# Where do hdfs directories reside in linux?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, hadoop2

Running my first map-reduce program. I created a directory in hdfs using

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir input
```

The directories created this way reside in hdfs home dir i.e /usr/hdfs (..?) But I couldn't find the directory 'input' I created above anywhere in my linux OS. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually we cannot see the hdfs directories directly so there are two methods to see the file in hdfs file system location

1st method is from terminal

```
hdfs dfs -ls /user/cloudera
```

so that you can see the files in hdfs filesystem in 'cloudera' named directory

2nd method is using the browser.

http://localhost:50070 in this you have to go to browse file system and see all files that are stored in hdfs file system.

Comment: The user is asking for the location of such a HDFS directory in the underlying Unix file system. It seems he/she already knows how to find that folder in HDFS.

Comment: Nevertheless, I agree with you: there is not a direct mapping between the HDFS folder and a Unix file system folder; the last one only store metadata regarding the HDFS structure.

Comment: No,he said that he want to find the 'input' named directory in the hdfs file system.
According to me he has created a new directory first time in distributed file system so he may thought that by browsing the file system he can find that 'input' directory that he had created

Comment: @SaiTarunPallati hdfs dfs -ls (without providing the path) shows me the input directory. It didn't work with path because in my case the path /usr/hdfs is wrong. Through page http://localhost:50070    Utility->Browse the file system option I got to know that the correct path is /user/cloudera

Comment: yes we can use hdfs dfs -ls command only when we know the exact directory if nt it seems to be difficult to search via terminal.So, browsing hadoop administration in browser is more preferable thanks for your information

Answer (score 2):

It is defined in [hdfs-default.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml):

> dfs.datanode.data.dir
>
> Determines where on the local filesystem an DFS data node should store
> its blocks. If this is a comma-delimited list of directories, then
> data will be stored in all named directories, typically on different
> devices. Directories that do not exist are ignored.

The default value is:

> file://${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/data

And detail about **hadoop.tmp.dir** can be find in [core-default.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to map the directories more directly is to use a block device driver such as hadoop-fuse:

```
  yum install hadoop-hdfs-fuse
  mkdir -p <mount_point>
  hadoop-fuse-dfs dfs://<name_node_hostname>:<namenode_port(def:8082)> <mount_point>
```